# Rendering tab data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using basic jQuery to render tab data.  I was wondering if anybody could comment on how to refactor the `click()` event handlers, and any general guidance or advice.

Here's the code/output in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jberczel/Q4zVH/).

```
('#tab1').click(function() {
  $("#page").empty().html("<p>Here is our menu: Crispy Duck, Shrimp Tempura, Christmas Roll</p> ");
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

$("#tab2").click(function() {
  $("#page").empty().html("<p>We're located at: 13352 Minnieville Rd., Woodbridge, VA </p>");
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

$("#tab3").click(function() {
  $("#page").empty().html("<p>We can be reached at: (555)555-5555.</p>");
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine these using a helper function with a closure.

```
function bindTabClickToSetPageContent(selector, content) {
    $(selector).click(function () {
        $("#page").html(content);
        $("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
}

bindTabClickToSetPageContent("#tab1", 
    "<p>Here is our menu: Crispy Duck, Shrimp Tempura, Christmas Roll</p>");
bindTabClickToSetPageContent("#tab2", 
    "<p>We're located at: 13352 Minnieville Rd., Woodbridge, VA</p>");
bindTabClickToSetPageContent("#tab3", 
    "<p>We can be reached at: (555)555-5555.</p>");
```

> Note: I dropped the call to [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) since [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) performs the same function before replacing the content.

Comment: I like this approach.  Also thanks for the note regarding the `empty` call.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply put your common code in a `function`

```
function giveItAName(htmlValue,self){

 $("#page").empty().html(htmlValue);
 $("a").removeClass("active");
 $(self).addClass("active");
}
```

And call this `function` accordingly

```
('#tab1').click(function() {
giveItAName("<p>Here is our menu: Crispy Duck, Shrimp Tempura, Christmas Roll</p> ",this);
});
```

And so on ...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one function that takes into account the ID of the element clicked on to determine what HTML to add to the DOM:

```
//the idea here is to match the number of the tab (#tab1 being number 1) with the data to display for that tab, the blank first index is because there is no #tab0
var tabData = ['', '<p>Here is our menu: Crispy Duck, Shrimp Tempura, Christmas Roll</p>', '<p>We\'re located at: 13352 Minnieville Rd., Woodbridge, VA </p>', '<p>We can be reached at: (555)555-5555.</p>'];

$('#tab1, #tab2, #tab3').click(function() {

    //get the index of the clicked tab via its ID
    var index = parseInt(this.id.replace('tab', ''), 10);

    //update DOM based on the index of the tab
    $("#page").empty().html(tabData[index]);

    //update links, I recommend adding a class to these links so you don't mess with others in the DOM
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

Here is an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4zVH/3/

You could also select your tabs by some other type of identifier, like a class, which would make this easier to expand.

Comment: someone here suggested an edit, where `parseInt(this.` was replaced by `~~`. jQuery pros, your call...